# Is given set open in product topology formed by product of order sets?

Tags: general-topology

We have two continuous functions $f$ and $g$ from topological space $X$ to topological space $Y$, where set $Y$ has the **order topology**.
Now, consider **Product topology $Y×Y$**. We define a subset $V$ of $Y×Y$,
$$
V = \{\;(f(x),g(x))\;|\;f(x)>g(x) \text{ for some $x$ belonging to } X\}
$$
Now, **can we say set $V$ is open in product topology $Y×Y$?**

My attempt:

I started by taking one element of $V$, $(f(a),g(a))$.
Now I want to find open sets $A$ and $B$ of $Y$, such that, $(f(a),g(a))$ belongs to $A×B$ which is a subset of $Y×Y$.
Then, by definition I can say $V$ is open in $Y×Y$.
Here, we can make use of fact that  $f$ and $g$ are continuous. 
For, each neighborhood $N$ of $f(a)$ there exist neighborhood $M$ of $a$ such that $f(M)$ is subset of $N$. And similarly for function $g$. 
But, here I'm confused which neighborhood of $Y$ I should choose?
Please prove or disprove this set is open or not.

Comment: No, we cannot say that because I will not allow you to speak for me.  On the other hand you can say what ever you want.  Are you attempting to ask "is V open?" but lack the courage to ask a direct question?

Comment: Your definition seems weird. It is well-known that in this situation $\{x: f(x) > g(x)\}$ is open in $X$ (also with $<$). This seems more along the lines of common interests..

Answer (score 3):

No.  Let $X=Y=\mathbb R$ and
$$ 
\forall x,\;f(x) = 1,\;g(x) = 0.
$$
$V = \{(1,0)\}$ which is not open.

Comment: Best 1-liner in quite a while.